# Docker phpmyadmin shows db_name but does not show the db tables

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin, lamp

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  phpapache:
        image: php:5.6-apache
        container_name: phpapache
        build: .
        ports :
         - 9080:80
        volumes:
         - ./www:/var/www/html/
  phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        environment:
         - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
         - PMA_HOST=mysql
         - PMA_USER=root
         - PMA_PASSWORD=password
        ports:
         - 8080:80
        volumes:
         - /sessions
  mysql:
        image: mysql:5.5
        container_name: mysql
        ports:
         - 3306:3306
        environment:
         - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
         - MYSQL_USER=root
         - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
        volumes:
         - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
```

If I go to `0.0.0.0:8080` from the browser I can see some of the databases (not all, supposed to be 6 databases) but all of them are empty. It does not load any database tables. How can I get the tables in the databases?

Comment: You can check the permission of the user which you use to go into the database.

Comment: I'd like to suggest not to use `root` user to connect mysql, expecially out side localhost. create other user and give it permission and use it.